# Hostname Could not be verified after making sslmode=verify-ca

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, postgresql-9.5

I try to connect my RDS instance and I don't want hostname to be checked by the SSL certificate.
So far I know making sslmode=verify-ca will not check hostname but for whatever reason it is doing so. Below is the stack trace for more details

Nov 20, 2019 6:06:11 PM org.postgresql.Driver connect
SEVERE: Connection error:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The hostname  could not be verified.
        at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:93)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:391)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:162)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:452)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:254)
        at amazon.jdbc.driver.spi.PostgresqlConnectionProvider.getConnection(PostgresqlConnectionProvider.java:85)
        at amazon.cj.dbaccess.FallbackWorker.iteratePasswordStore(FallbackWorker.java:101)
        at amazon.cj.dbaccess.FallbackWorker.getConnection(FallbackWorker.java:59)
        at amazon.cj.dbaccess.CacheController.getConnection(CacheController.java:153)
        at amazon.jdbc.driver.SecureDriver.connect(SecureDriver.java:174)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:307)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:728)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:662)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:480)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.(ConnectionPool.java:154)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:115)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:102)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:559)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:848)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:158)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:835)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:172)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1091)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:670)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:258)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5213)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1853)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Database logon failed url:jdbc:postgresql://:8194/fa_rhythm_db_dev?ssl=true;sslmode=verify-ca;sslrootcert=/apollo/env/RhythmTomcatBase/certs/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem moduleName:null properties:{sslrootcert=/apollo/env/RhythmTomcatBase/certs/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem} @ driver:class amazon.jdbc.driver.SecureDriver url:jdbc:amazon:postgresql://hostname:8194/fa_rhythm_db_dev?ssl=true;sslmode=verify-ca;sslrootcert=/apollo/env/RhythmTomcatBase/certs/rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem database:fa_rhythm user:pega module:null properties:{}

Answer (score 1):

> If the parameter sslmode is set to verify-ca, libpq will verify that the server is trustworthy by checking the certificate chain up to a trusted certificate authority (CA). If sslmode is set to verify-full, libpq will also verify that the server host name matches its certificate. The SSL connection will fail if the server certificate cannot be verified. verify-full is recommended in most security-sensitive environments.

From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/libpq-ssl.html)

`sslmode=require` can be used if you specifically know you are connecting to the right host and trust said host

Comment: when I added the `sslmode=require` to the DB connection URL, the error ->
HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The hostname **** could not be verified by hostnameverifier PgjdbcHostnameVerifier.